# Is it possible to simulate a browser POST form in C#?

Tags: c#, python

My C# client code doesn't seem to transmit a type="text" as a browser would.
The ramifications are that this server side Python code doesn't work:

```py
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def func():
        f = request.files['fname']
        alias = request.data['alias'] # works with request.files['alias'] though
```

Here's the C# client code :

```cs
static public async Task<System.IO.Stream> UploadAsync(string url, string alias, string docName, byte[] docBytes)
{
    // Converts inputs into HttpContent objects

    HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(alias);

    HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(docBytes);

    // create form data as Multipart (enctype="multipart/form-data")

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        // Add the HttpContent objects to the form data

        // <input type="text" name="alias" />
        formData.Add(stringContent, "alias", "alias");
        // <input type="file" name="fname" />
        formData.Add(bytesContent, "fname", "fname");

        // Invoke the request to the server

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, formData);

        Console.WriteLine("StatusCode = " + response.StatusCode);

        // ensure the request was a success
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use PostMan to test your endpoints.

Comment: I would try the form data as `FormUrlEncodedContent`.

Comment: "Is it possible..." Yes. You could write an entire browser in C# if you want.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the browser request with the c# request.  Make the headers in c# look exactly like the browser headers.  The default headers in c# are not the same as the browser so you probably have to add or modify a header.